# Closure of real interval in a topology with intervals with rational ends as a bsis.

Tags: general-topology

Given a Topolgy over $\mathbb{R}$ with intervals of the form $[p, q), p, q\in\mathbb{Q}$ as a basis, I'm interested in finding the closure of intervals with real ends, such as $\left(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\right)$.

I know the closure won't be the interval $\left[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\right]$, since $\mathbb{R} - \left[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\right]$ cannot be produced out of union of intervals with rational ends. How might I go about finding the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure is $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$, $\pm \sqrt{2}$ are indeed limit points since we can find points in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ in any neighbourhood of $\pm \sqrt{2}$, and obviously there can not be any limit point not in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.Note that since we can take *infinite*  unions $\mathbb{R}-[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ *can* be produced out of unions of intervals with rational endpoints.